# A Restrictive WHERE IN SQL Statement With UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the following tables:

- `cards`
- `uploads`
- `tags`
- `tag_upload`: Relation between a tag and an upload.
- `card_tag`: Relation between a tag and a card.

Card 1 has a relation to the tags "event", "rmc", and "patient".

Upload 1 has a relation to the tags "event" and "patient".

Upload 2 has a relation to the tags "event", "rmc", and "patient".

#### Query 1:

I've selected the tags "event" and "patient".

It should return Upload 1, Upload 2, and Card 1.

#### Query 2:

I've selected the tags "event", "rmc", and "patient".

It should return Upload 1 and Card 1.

#### The Problem:

I'm currently using the following but when I do this Query 2 returns the same as Query 1:

What would the query look like that would select a card if it had the tags in it?
Could I see an example or logic flow you might use?

This is my first version trying to get what I want down.  Will be turned into testable code right after with PHPSpec.

## Solution

Thank you eggyal!

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT   cards.id, cards.name, cards.type,
             cards.updated_at, cards.created_at, cards.image
    FROM     cards
        JOIN card_tag ON card_tag.card_id = cards.id
        JOIN tags     ON card_tag.tag_id  =  tags.id
    WHERE    NOT tags.deleted
         AND cards.type NOT IN ('','libraries')
         AND cards.account_user_id = 1
         AND tags.name IN ('rmc', 'test')
    GROUP BY cards.id
    HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT   uploads.id, uploads.name, uploads.type,
             uploads.updated_at, uploads.created_at, uploads.image
    FROM     uploads
        JOIN tag_upload ON tag_upload.upload_id = uploads.id
        JOIN tags     ON tag_upload.tag_id  =  tags.id
    WHERE    NOT tags.deleted
         AND uploads.type NOT IN ('','libraries')
         AND uploads.account_user_id = 1
         AND tags.name IN ('rmc','test')
    GROUP BY uploads.id
    HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = 2
) AS qry
    ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC
    LIMIT 0, 35
```

Comment: At first, take PHP out of the equation, start with the verbatim SQL queries. Then pinpoint the problem within those two queries you compare down to the actual matter, so that your example - let's say ideally - can live with two tables if not even one to make the example and show your problem. Don't just paste live code. Instead create a programming question that contains something reproduceable (or is self-containing). SQL-Fiddle can help here, too.

Comment: @hakre If I could just see example of how to tackle this problem I'll be able to solve it myself.  Just not sure about the logic flow.

Comment: Well, it was not meant that an example must 100% work. Just some example data and then what you've got so far, even not yet perfect (perfect comes later anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, consider joining your tables, grouping and filtering the results:

```sql
SELECT   cards.id, cards.name, cards.type,
         cards.updated_at, cards.created_at, cards.image
FROM     cards
    JOIN card_tag ON card_tag.card_id = cards.id
    JOIN tags     ON card_tag.tag_id  =  tags.id
WHERE    NOT deleted
     AND cards.type NOT IN ('','libraries')
     AND cards.account_user_id = ?
     AND tags.name IN ('event','patient')
GROUP BY cards.id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id) = 2
```

If `(card_id, tag_id)` is *guaranteed* to be unique in `card_tag`, one can replace `COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id)` with the more performant `COUNT(*)`.

One can then `UNION` with a similar query on the `uploads` table.

Comment: Yes `card_id` and `tag_id` are both primary keys in their respective tables.  `WHERE NOT deleted` Is that supposed to be `WHERE NOT tags.deleted`? This is awesome! I'm getting my `UNION` setup with this.

Comment: @MichaelCalkins: To be honest, it's all just an attempt to interpret your intentions from your existing query (which doesn't seem to align very well with your problem description).

Comment: that's my bad I removed all the PHP that I was using to generate it and it kinda lost all it's relevance.  Ty so much though!